# replacing a string in a vector without positioning

Tags: c++, vector, fstream

In the code i am working on now I have a vector load itself from a txt file now I was trying to see if their was a way to replace certain words in the vector without needing a position or anything
so for example if the txt contained a list of animals and i wanted to change bird to book how would i do that without need the position of the letters

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

vector <string> test;

int main()
{
  string file;
  fstream fout( "Vector.txt" );
  while  ( !fout.eof())
  {
   getline(fout,file);
   test.push_back(file);
  }
  fout.close();


  for( int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++)
  {
   cout << test[i] << endl;
  }


  system("pause");
}
```

txt contains:

dog
cat
bird
hippo
wolf

Comment: it's not clear what you have in test[i] (a word, a sentence ?).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to replace words in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053687/trying-to-replace-words-in-a-string)

Comment: can you post an input txt example and one possibly output expected? I can't understand what you want to do.

Comment: well basically without having to know the position i want to change a word in the txt file to something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
typedef std::istream_iterator<string> isitr;

ifstream fin("Vector.txt");
vector <string> test{ isitr{fin}, isitr{} }; // vector contains strings

map<string,string> dict{ // replacements dictionary
    {"bird", "book"}, {"cat", "kitten"}
};

for(auto& x: test) // x must be a reference
{
    auto itr = dict.find(x);
    if(itr != dict.end()) // if a match was found
        x = itr->second; // replace x with the found replacement
                         // (this is why x must be a reference)
}

for(const auto& x: test)
    cout << test << " ";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`std::transform()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

```
std::string bird2book(const string &str)
{
    if (str == "bird")
        return "book";
    return str;
}

std::transform(test.begin(), test.end(), test.begin(), bird2book);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`std::replace`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/replace/)

```
std::replace (test.begin(), test.end(), "bird", "book");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use STL!! It's our power. Everything you need:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> words;

    const std::map<std::string, std::string> words_to_replace{
            { "bird", "book" }, { "cat", "table" }
        };
    auto end = words_to_replace.cend();

    std::transform(
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>{ std::ifstream{ "file.txt" } },
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
        std::back_inserter(words),
        [&](const std::string& word) {
            auto word_pos = words_to_replace.find(word);
            return (word_pos != end) ? word_pos->second : word;
        });

    std::copy(words.cbegin(), words.cend(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```